# Dynamic dispatching OOP

Tags: c++, oop

I've written code in cpp to test my understanding of dynamic dispatching. I think that in my program the output should be "**I'm in NT**". My reasoning is:

1. tMethod is defined to be virtual, so dynamic binding will be used
2. at run time the class-type of `test` is NT, so call to `test->tMethod(ont)` should look for the implementation inside NT
3. actual parameter `ont` is of type NT, so exact match is found to be NT's impementation of tMethod

However, the output of this program is "**I'm in T**".

What is wrong in my reasoning?

```
 #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    class T {

        public:
            virtual void tMethod(T){
                cout<<"I'm in T"<<endl;
            }

    };

    class NT: public T{
        public:
            void tMethod(NT){
                cout<<"I'm in NT"<<endl;
            }

    };


    int main()
    {
        NT ont;

        T* test=new NT();

        test->tMethod(ont);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `NT::tMethod()` takes different parameter type to `N::tMethod()` so it doesn't override. use the `override` keyword to protect against this

Comment: But despite that, maybe not in this example, he can't use any polymorphic abilities and might run into undefined behavior because he passed it by value. Slicing, for example.

Comment: @OlzhasZhumabek That wouldn't be undefined behaviour, unless the classes have UB bugs in their implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This method:

```
void tMethod(NT){
```

does not override this one:

```
virtual void tMethod(T){
```

you have changed parameter type from `NT` to `T`

You can add override to turn this bug it into error:

```
void tMethod(NT) override {
```

will output:

> main.cpp:16:18: error: 'void NT::tMethod(NT)' marked 'override', but does not override
>                void tMethod(NT) override {

[edit]

Your actual question is why C++ does not allow to overload functions across class inheritence, specifically to be able to access derived class functions using base class pointer. The reason is that language does not support this functionality. You can find similar question in Bjarne Stroustrup FAQ: [Why doesn't overloading work for derived classes?](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#overloadderived)

Comment: Why is it required that it overrides it? I agree that this is not redefinition (I think this is overloading). But still class NT has two methods, one inherited and a new method for the type NT. Now in my case, when lookup for the appropriate function takes place, why is function with formal parameter of type T chosen when actual parameter is of type NT?

Comment: `test->tMethod(ont);` make a function call on pointer of class  type T, this means only methods from T will be called. Change `T* test` to `NT* test` and `void tMethod(NT)` will get called.

Comment: It is pointer of class type T, but at run time it points to class type NT. Shouldn't then methods be searched inside NT? I think that this is the main idea of polymorphism.

Comment: Only properly overriden methods will be searched inside NT. If function is virtual then correct method is found using virtual method table (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table). No overloading is allowed here.

Comment: This answers my question. Please add this line to your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`NT::tMethod()` takes different parameter type to `N::tMethod()` so it doesn't override. Use the `override` keyword to protect against this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class T
{

public:
    virtual void tMethod(T) {
        cout << "I'm in T" << endl;
    }
};

class NT: public T
{
public:
    void tMethod(NT) override { // use override keyword here
        cout << "I'm in NT" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    NT ont;

    T* test = new NT();

    test->tMethod(ont);

    return 0;
}
```

Now you should get a compile error because you marked `MT::tMethod()` as `override` but it doesn't because it takes a different parameter type.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use pointer or reference to base class as an argument in virtual method. If you need to work with a derived class in the overriden method then you can use dynamic_cast.

```
class T {

    public:
        virtual void tMethod(T*){
            cout<<"I'm in T"<<endl;
        }

};

class NT: public T{
    public:
        virtual void tMethod(T* t) override {
            NT* nt=dynamic_cast<NT*>(t);
            if (nt)
            {
                cout<<"I'm in NT as NT"<<endl;
            }
        }    
};


int main()
{
    NT ont;

    T* test=new NT();

    test->tMethod(&ont);

    return 0;
}
```